# Why are my styles not taking effect in codesandbox?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, codesandbox

If you look at this tiny CodeSandbox project: https://codesandbox.io/s/0oj4z7ko00

Notice in index.html the following two snippets:

```
<style type="text/css">
  #container {
    background: yellow;
  }
</style>
```

and

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

This container is where React renders the rest of the app (which works), but its background isn't yellow! Why not?

---

Furthermore, if you look at components/Presentational.js, you'll find the following snippet:

```
<div className={data % 2 === 0 ? "even" : "odd"}>
```

and in index.html, some styles for these class names:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .even { color: red; }
  .odd { color: green; }
</style>
```

Notice that the class name is correctly assigned to the element based on the value of the `data` prop, yet the styles aren't taking effect and the text remains black.

In both cases, the styles are nowhere to be found in the inspector, so I really don't think they are being overridden. But what the hell is happening? Why are my styles not taking effect in CodeSandbox?

Comment: Guess thats some kind of codebox thing, maybe only updates to body are allowed? You can just add an `index.css` file and import it in your `index.js`.

Comment: yes that works, thanks

Comment: @Shawn the CSB link seems to work. by "yes that works", do you mean you were able to fix the problem with sn42's answer?

Comment: @SungKim yes, problem solved

Answer (score 3):

save that file after any changes done like save HTML, CSS, .jss files.

Click on File tab(on top left) -> save